# autoKrige gives different results if data frame columns removed

Tags: r, kriging

I may be doing something wrong here, but I find that if I simplify my data frame by removing irrelevant columns the autoKrige function in the automap library gives different results. I have reproduced this problem with the meuse data in the automap library.

```
library(automap)
data(meuse)
colnames(meuse)
 [1] "x"       "y"       "cadmium" "copper"  "lead"    "zinc"    "elev"   
 [8] "dist"    "om"      "ffreq"   "soil"    "lime"    "landuse" "dist.m" 

coordinates(meuse) =~ x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) =~ x+y
kriging_result_01 = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse)
plot(kriging_result_01)

meuse <- NULL
data(meuse)
meuse <- meuse[, c(1,2,6)]

coordinates(meuse) =~ x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) =~ x+y
kriging_result_02 = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse)
plot(kriging_result_02)

identical(kriging_result_01, kriging_result_02)
[1] FALSE
```

The plots are also different in their detail.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: I didn't search in details why, but I guess this is related to how the `new_data` object is calculated when it is not provided to `autoKrige`. Using `autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, meuse.grid)` gives identical results.

Comment: If you look at `kriging_result_01$krige_output@grid` and `kriging_result_02$krige_output@grid`, you can see the calculated `new_data` objects are slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the removed columns, but the grid to apply the fitted model on. Using your example, you can see:

```
library(automap)
set.seed(42)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) =~ x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) =~ x+y
kriging_result_01 = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse)

meuse <- NULL
data(meuse)
meuse <- meuse[, c(1,2,6)]
coordinates(meuse) =~ x+y

kriging_result_02 = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse)


kriging_result_01$krige_output@grid
                            x1           x2
cellcentre.offset 178635.12844 329744.86186
cellsize              32.93423     32.93423
cells.dim             84.00000    118.00000
```

and

```
kriging_result_02$krige_output@grid
                            x1           x2
cellcentre.offset 178614.42379 329741.35016
cellsize              32.93423     32.93423
cells.dim             85.00000    118.00000
```

As you can see, the grids are slightly different, with 4999 and 
4996 grid points respectively.

If you use

```
kriging_result_01 = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, meuse.grid)
kriging_result_02 = autoKrige(zinc~1, meuse, meuse.grid)

kriging_result_01$krige_output@grid
                       x      y
cellcentre.offset 178460 329620
cellsize              40     40
cells.dim             78    104

kriging_result_02$krige_output@grid
                       x      y
cellcentre.offset 178460 329620
cellsize              40     40
cells.dim             78    104
```

The grids are similar.

Comment: @WilliamChivers if this answer solved your question, consider accepting it as a correct answer - by clicking the grey tick under its score.